# Disable only vertical scrolling of UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, scrollview

I have scrollView inside my custom UITableViewCell. Now I want to disable the only vertical scrolling of scrollView inside the Custom UITableViewCell, So I can detect the vertical scrolling of its parentView UITableView during its vertical scrolling.

**Note:** However custom cell should have horizontal scrolling every time.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can try this:

```
self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
```

Or you can try set the `contentSize`, like:

```
myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myScroll.contentSize.width,myScroll.frame.size.height);
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

For UIScrollView, scrolling depends on the contentSize property. So, if you set the vertical content size to the frame of your scrollview. It should work.

```
let ContentSize_X: CGFloat = 1000 // set this to your contentsize in horizontal direction

let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: scrollFrame)
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(ContentSize_X, scrollView.frame.size.height)
```